# Double rows when running query

Tags: sql, join, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am using the query:

```
SELECT SALESQUOTATIONLINE.QUOTATIONID, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.CREATEDDATETIME, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.CUSTACCOUNT AS CustomerAccount, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.COMPANY, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.DELIVERYNAME, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.LINENUM AS LineNumber, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.ITEMID, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.NAME AS ItemName, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.QTYORDERED, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.SALESQTY, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.REMAININVENTPHYSICAL, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.REMAINSALESPHYSICAL, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.CURRENCYCODE, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.SALESPRICE, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.PRICEUNIT, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.LINEAMOUNT, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.SALESUNIT, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.COSTPRICE, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.QBE_LINESTATUS AS LineStatus, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.ISSM_LINEREALISTIC AS LineRealistic, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.QBE_MARGE AS Marge, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.QBE_MARGEPERCENTTA AS MargePercentTA, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.RECEIPTDATEREQUESTED, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.SHIPPINGDATEREQUESTED, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.CONFIRMEDDLV, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.QBE_DLVTIMEQUOTATION AS DlvTimeQuotation, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.QBE_DLVTIMEQUOTSPEC AS DlvTimeQuotSpec, SALESQUOTATIONLINE.CUSTOMERREF, 
       SALESQUOTATIONLINE.DEFAULTDIMENSION, tb1.PERSONNELNUMBER AS WorkerSalesResponsibleCode, tb1.QBE_EMPLTYPE AS EmployeeType, 
       tb2.PERSONNELNUMBER AS WorkerSalesTakerCode, SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.BUSRELACCOUNT AS BusRelAccount, 
       SMMBUSRELTABLE.ELG_REVENUECATID AS RevenueCatId, SMMBUSRELTABLE.POTENTIAL AS Potential
FROM SALESQUOTATIONLINE 
INNER JOIN SALESQUOTATIONTABLE ON SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.QUOTATIONID = SALESQUOTATIONLINE.QUOTATIONID 
INNER JOIN SMMBUSRELTABLE ON SMMBUSRELTABLE.BUSRELACCOUNT = SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.BUSRELACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN HCMWORKER AS tb1 ON tb1.RECID = SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.WORKERSALESRESPONSIBLE 
INNER JOIN HCMWORKER AS tb2 ON tb2.RECID = SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.WORKERSALESTAKER
```

At the moment i have added the join:

```
INNER JOIN SMMBUSRELTABLE ON SMMBUSRELTABLE.BUSRELACCOUNT = SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.BUSRELACCOUNT`
```

I am getting double rows with different RevenueCatId en Potential (Both 1 blank and 1 with the actual record info).

What am I doing wrong with this JOIN?

Comment: Missing 'DataAreaId' on the joins of SMMBUSRELTABLE, SALESQUOTATIONTABLE and SALESQUOTATIONLINE tables?  Consider DataAreaId to be the '[company](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242144.aspx)' row attribute, of which HCMWORKER has none.

Comment: When you are writing sql queries include dataareaid and partition on join conditions. http://dynamicserppros.com/dataareaid-and-partition-and-very-slow-queries/   Shared tables do not have dataareadid too  http://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/183372

Comment: Thank you, i will adjust my query and join dataareaid and partition.